# count numbers by month within date ranges held in separate table

Tags: t-sql, range

I have tried asking this before but do not think i did a good job wording my request, so apologies.

I have a table containing data as per:

`;WITH MONTHSCTE AS ( 
  SELECT 
    ReportMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -OFFSET.X))), 
    Start12Months = DATEADD(MONTH, -12, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -OFFSET.X))),
    End12Months = EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -OFFSET.X)))),
    [Month] = DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -OFFSET.X)))),
    [MonthName] = DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -OFFSET.X)))),
    [Year] = DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -OFFSET.X))))
  FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) OFFSET(X) 
)
,CTE2 AS
    (
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ReportMonth) AS [Order]
    ,*
    FROM 
    MONTHSCTE
    )
SELECT * FROM CTE2`

[image]

I would like to use the date ranges in this dataset to query another.

Lets say i have a table called Attendances showing PatientID and date of attendance. I would like to query this 'Attendances' table for each of the date ranges in the above dataset.

So:

A count of how many patients between 2018-05-01 and 30-04-2019 attended 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.. times in each respective date range.

The same for patients between 01-06-2018 and 2019-05-31 and so on for each range in the above dataset.

The final product should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Is there an alternative that does not incorporate a Cursor?

Comment: This could be done by building a complex dynamic SQL statement using group bys, pivot, and probably a few CTE-hosted nested queries. A big question would be, how how many "Attendance" columns might you end up with? SQL is not a good language for complex layouts and fancy formats; ideally, you would prepare the data to be formatted (`count(*)...join on date between firstdate and lastdate...group by month`) and pass it to an application to handle the final formatting.